# WCF call throws: "The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'net.tcp'." exception

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS7.

This is the app.config for my service hosted in IIS

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings />
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="querierSearch.Querier.WCF.QuerierBehavior"
      name="querierSearch.Querier.WCF.Querier">
      <endpoint 
         address="net.tcp://localhost:808/querierSearch.Querier.WCF/Querier.svc"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="EndPointTCP"
        contract="querierSearch.Querier.WCF.IQuerier" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="querierSearch.Querier.WCF.QuerierBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And below is the app.config in the client that references the WCF Service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="EndPointTCP" closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
          openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
          transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" 
          transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" 
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" 
          maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
          axArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
          maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
            protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/Search.Querier.WCF/Querier.svc"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EndPointTCP"
        contract="SearchQueryService.IQuerier"
        name="EndPointTCP">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="joeuser@company.com" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

For some reason I still get "The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'net.tcp'." exception .

I cannot figure out why.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it turns out i was missing the mex endpoint...
woops

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

You're asking it to enable HTTP on a TCP service, which seems like it might cause some problems.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that the  `behaviorConfiguration` in the web.config is **deleted** after I refresh the the `Service References`.

(My `behaviorConfiguration` uses a `clientVia` address rather than a standard endpoint address to allow it to traverse the firewall).